# If NetStandard target platform is just an interface, where/when do you write the implementation?

Tags: .net-standard

I am very confused with the technical aspect of the NetStandard target platform.

My only understanding is that its just an interface. This concept make sense.
But now here is where my first confusion is:

How can it be just an interface if the developer writes actual code in the said project?

Second confusion:

How and when does the actual implementation/DLL for a NetStandard DLL get resolved and thus used?

Comment: You don't provide the implementation, Microsoft did.  There is more than one. It gets resolved when your program starts running by mapping a type from the .netstandard declaration to the actual runtime implementation.  The extra level of indirection provided by this mapping made .netstandard possible.  And made it possible to create a class library that is usable on multiple platforms.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I am referring to my own custom projects which i created as NetStandard.

Comment: You must provide the implementation of your own classes.  All that .netstandard does it isolate you from the runtime support class implementations.

Comment: so this means a .net core as well as a .net framework project can reference a netstandard dll?

Comment: Yes.  And Mono, Xamarin, UWP, Unity projects, your class library is usable in all of them.  They have dramatically different runtime implementations, that nasty detail is hidden and won't affect your code.

Comment: Then what is the point of creating a NetStandard project?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an "interface" in so much as it's just a standard that is compatible with both .NET Framework and .NET Core (among other .NET implementations). You can still write concrete classes based on NetStandard.

You can see all the implementations NetStandard supports here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

This is beneficial in cases where you want to create a common library that can be consumed by all sorts of applications that are based on DotNetCore, NET Framework, Mono, Xamarin, etc.

Comment: So when i see blogs attempting to explain NetStandard target framework as just an interface, it is absolutely incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

> My only understanding is that its just an interface.

People use the "interface" concept because in C#, that's obviously a well known paradigm to say "If you implement this interface, you must provide these methods".

When used in the context of .NET Standard, they generally don't mean a literal C# interface, they mean that if you say "I implement .NET Standard 2.1", that means you provide implementations for all of the methods that .NET Standard 2.1 requires.

It's just an easy thought process to think of .NET Standard as one massive C# interface with thousands of methods that you must write a body for to say you support that version of .NET Standard.

> How can it be just an interface if the developer writes actual code in the said project?

Because when you write code in a .NET Standard project/library, you are basically saying "I am writing this against an interface, but I don't know who will be calling this, just that I can call method XYZ and it will work".

Similar to if you were writing a class that called an interface method, you don't need to know the class implementation, only that if you call the method on that interface, it "should" work.

> How and when does the actual implementation/DLL for a NetStandard DLL get resolved and thus used?

A .NET Standard DLL cannot be run on it's own. It does not have a "runtime". For all practical purposes, you will find that you have a .NET Core Web App calling a .NET Standard library, therefore it runs under the context of .NET Core.

If you instead have a .NET Framework Winforms project calling a .NET Standard Library, then you are running under .NET Framework runtime.

So to answer your question, it gets "resolved" at runtime depending on who is calling it.

Comment: See this article. http://www.codedigest.com/quick-start/9/what-is-netstandard#:~:text=Net%20Standard%20is%20a%20specification,Here%2C%20Platform%20means%20full%20.

Comment: "...It does not have implementations or a runtime, it just defines a specification what different..." This sentence is what is confusing. If im writing a .NetStandard project, then clearing im writing implementation!

Comment: You are writing code that relies on an interface called .NET Standard. When you write a .NET Standard library, you are not implementing .NET Standard, you are *using* it. Put another way, if I have a piece of code that calls a method on an interface, my code is not an implementation of that interface is it? It's simply calling it.